# "For the sake of" vs "for sake of"

Tags: phrases, idioms, phrase-usage, definite-articles

Are *for the sake of* and *for sake of* both equally correct and idiomatic?

The dictionaries I know list only the former, while the latter also seems to be commonplace.

Answer (score 3):

I don't recognise "for sake of" as an English phrase.

Looking at the iWeb corpus, I see that it does occur: 1990 instances, against 120670 of "for the sake of".

It is a much less common variant, and if I it occurred in something I was editing, I would regard it as a mistake, and add the "the".

**Added to the answer by Jerzy Brzóska, 1 November 2021:** It's [occurrence in Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for+the+sake+of%2Cfor+sake+of+&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfor%20the%20sake%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfor%20sake%20of%3B%2Cc0) is also at least a hundred times less common than that of "for the sake of".

Comment: It is literally always "for sake of the argument", as a set phrase. What kind of editor does not recognize this and adds "the"? Quite a few, apparently, as there are some results for this, too, but that's just wrong by common sense. The n-gram that you linked is nonsense, by the way. The results for the the-less variant include the the in the overview, and it's well known that this interface is lying to the user.

Comment: @vectory, I am a native English speaker who does not recognise _for sake of the argument_ as an English phrase. I would _always_ assume it was a mistake for _for the sake of argument_.

Comment: I did not link an ngram: that was inserted by Jerzy Brzóska, who should not have added it without taking VERY CLEAR AND PUBLIC RESPONSIBILITY for having done so.